# Cannot instantiate spark SessionState

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I run into this problem when submit my python program through spark-submit.

```
    df = (sc.binaryFiles(archives).map(lambda r: {'file_name': r[0], 'content' : bytearray(r[1])}).toDF(schema))
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 57, in toDF
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 526, in createDataFrame
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/py4j-0.10.3-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 79, in deco
pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: u"Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState':"
17/05/02 10:25:01 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
```

I am using spark version 2.0.0.2.5.3.0-37, py4j version 0.10.3 and python 2.7. Can you tell me how to fix it?